# How to create partial string search function in Excel looking across entire Array

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a Search response in Excel to look for a partial string in what could be a paragraph.  This will then return the location of that cell to determine the row needed to pull the data from.  I have tried many different ways including Index Match to process this but the formula is either pulling the wrong data or giving me a #N/A from this first function to verify it is collecting the right pieces:

```
=INDEX(Sheet15!D:D, MATCH("*AS5553*", Sheet15!E:E, 0))
```

This is trying to force the data to only search Column E for a match but both E and F contain the information we might need.  All data is currently stored in Table1.

Is it possible to create a search function with nested IF loops for both columns without writing VBA?

Edit - Adding an example table.  The idea would be to search for Medditerranean and it would return the first result.  There are repeat strings in the text it will need to navigate.

[image: example table]

Comment: Would you kindly provide some data or screenshoot so i can replicate your problem and i can give you some suggestions please?

Comment: Will there only be one cell that matches the search?